# Specify function parameter types in TypeScript mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have two functions that take a single `options` argument with differing properties, except for `type`, which is used to identify the function.

```
type FuncAOptions = {
    type: 'A'
    opt1: string
    opt2: boolean
}

function funcA(options: FuncAOptions): number {
    if (!options.opt1) throw new Error('Missing required option')
    return 1
}

type FuncBOptions = {
    type: 'B'
    opt3: number
    opt4: (a: number) => number
}

function funcB(options: FuncBOptions): string {
    if (!options.opt3) throw new Error('Missing required option')
    return 'B'
}
```

I then have a map of these functions, with an associated mapped type, so that I can call the functions conditionally with variable runtime data.

```
type AllFunctions = FuncAOptions | FuncBOptions

type FunctionMap = { [K in AllFunctions['type']]: (options: any) => any; }

const functionMap: FunctionMap = {
    A: funcA,
    B: funcB
}

function callFunction(type: keyof typeof functionMap, options: any) {
    return functionMap[type](options)
}
```

When I call the functions directly, I get the proper type-checking to know if I'm passing an incorrect set of options. I want to be able to do the same when calling the function through the intermediary method.

```
callFunction('A', { type: 'B', opt3: 'Hello' }) // NO TS ERROR
funcA({ type: 'B', opt3: 'Hello' }) // TS ERROR: The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'FuncAOptions'
```

I like having the map typed with `K in AllFunctions['type']` because when I add a function to `AllFunctions`, I am reminded that I need to add the key-value pair to `functionMap`.

[Full example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=140&pln=36&pc=1#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-S0pSrBAA)

Comment: In `callFunction` you have typed `options` as `any`. That means that Typescript won't typecheck that parameter

Comment: The recommended approach to something like this is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); the refactoring for your example looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKvgDm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Amazing, @jcalz — exactly what I was looking for! It seems I have to go at this from the other direction — define the map first, and if I want a union of the possible set of options, I can generate that automatically from the map. ([line 33 here](https://shorturl.at/bFMZ4))

Comment: Yes (although I don't know why you're calling it `AllFunctions` instead of `AllFuncOptions` or `FuncOptions`).  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `functionMap[type](options)` to type check without loosening things up with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), then you'll need to write it terms of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a base key-value type or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of that type.  This is as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

Essentially you want `type` to be seen as some generic type `K`, and `functionMap` to be seen as some mapped type like `{[P in keyof FuncOptionMap]: (arg: FuncOptionMap[P]) => FuncRetMap[P]}` and for `options` to be seen as type `FuncOptionMap[K]`.  Then the compiler can conclude that the function `functionMap[type]` is of type `(arg: FuncOptionMap[K]) => FuncRetMap[K]`, and is therefore callable with `options` as an argument, and will return the corresponding return type `FuncRetMap[K]`.  So we'll need to define `FuncOptionMap` and `FuncRetMap` in terms of the values you have.

You might have hoped that you could have done this with `type` merely being the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) equivalent to `keyof FuncOptionMap` without needing generics.  But TypeScript can't follow that sort of logic, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The recommended approach is to use generic indexing into mapped types instead; indeed microsoft/TypeScript#47109 is the solution to microsoft/TypeScript#30581 (or at least the closest we have to a solution).

It could look like this:

```
const _functionMap = {
    A: funcA,
    B: funcB
}

type FuncOptionMap =
    { [K in keyof typeof _functionMap]: Parameters<typeof _functionMap[K]>[0] }
type FuncRetMap =
    { [K in keyof typeof _functionMap]: ReturnType<typeof _functionMap[K]> }

const functionMap: { [K in keyof FuncOptionMap]: (options: FuncOptionMap[K]) => FuncRetMap[K] }
    = _functionMap
```

Essentially we rename your `functionMap` to `_functionMap` and then later assign it back with the `FuncOptionMap` and `FuncRetMap` types computed from it.  It might look like a no-op, since the type of `_functionMap` and the type of `functionMap` appear to be identical.  But this is actually very important; the compiler can only follow the logic when things are written as this mapping. If you try to use `_functionMap` instead of `functionMap` in what follows, the compiler will lose the thread and output an error.

Continuing:

```
function callFunction<K extends keyof FuncOptionMap>(
    type: K, options: FuncOptionMap[K]
) {
    return functionMap[type](options); // okay
}
```

That type checks, and the return type is `FuncRetMap[K]`.  Now you get the error you expected:

```
callFunction('A', { type: 'B', opt3: 'Hello' }) // error!
// ---------------------> ~~~ B is not A
```

and when you call it the compiler knows how the output type as depends on the input type:

```
console.log(callFunction(
    "B",
    { type: "B", opt3: 1, opt4: x => x + 1 }
).toLowerCase()); // okay, the compiler knows it's string and not number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYEEDyZgEsD2CDOUAvFAN4BQUVUokAXFAOQqOXU6YCMD+wATlgQBzNlQ7AATAwBGOHABsIAQwTkAvuXIAzREmx4oO5CgAU43AQbxjGfQQCUDBHAC20iHzKioWLVBMAhOZ4+AB04pz2NAAWfDgA7lAIEIkAonxxfCaMALJY+PiCQlB8EACOcFilACZQwQiM9t6lwHB8CFCc6pq00NZIAEK2FoQkFNQ04BAMjAOsE+IAzE6u7nze4gAsDCZKK24eUUQAfEmrHt3aunaGugNmmCNWd8MhjlC8AsJeE77+QY8QuFMIsosBYgkkikoOlMtk8gUiiVypUanVAQ0mhMWm0OrNWBpyEgQsAoAB9Ix6Cw5JRgYg-agoBiUlAAGm8A2Zd0uvVguleCBpdKI3lIUAA2gBpHwdADWEBAOD8vSV5MpdiFAF0GAAFJR8JQuCDADz4AA8Kr8FOu1NpUs1x3FAAZNVANLz+gAlY1C4iiiXSwRQeWK5VTVXW5Aa2naqDe1rtAAqUwt4at6ttYHtp0JxIIpIzeCFDDFUplwYVqv6Aq1O3q+GeyBrdslmqOpy9Ppbro0ExIkapRdpmkLHSQSnk8n6djN0ogAA8TQhqoQQ1X+RihccTN5egxJaz0XYG3ym5vu+QouNqDj2rco5nxb1NQ9j-YANxQAD0X7qsqUICXOOk7ThY2QsIeYp7kwcyHksMwABIQJOOCMG6UQ-jCnqelcxgmFBUwzLBR7LEwSEoWhagYb+qTYZoeb4AoEChPIOBCCYwFTjaeA7hMABEAx8eyEwEfQUACUJJEMJwcGYNsUDzsQpyKQA1J0bqXqEwA4AAMgkHgAMJKPgEAmPYH7fr+fHSHxmh2ZoQA)